# Pyhton Move Between Rooms

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to move between rooms using a dict and I can navigate if the room only has 1 location to move to but when it has more than one I get an error.

```
# The dictionary links a room to other rooms.
rooms = {
    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}


def instructions():
    print("Milestone for Module 6.")
    print("Type 'go' and then the direction want to move in lowercase")
    print("You can type exit to leave the game after this menu")

current_room = 'Great Hall'
direction = ''

while True:
    print('\nYou are in:', current_room)

    direction = input('Move which direction?')
    print('You entered:', direction)

    if direction == 'quit':
        print('Game Exited')
        break

    elif direction == 'go north':
        if 'North' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = str(*rooms[current_room].values())
        else:
            print('Unable to move to that location, try again.')

    elif direction == 'go south':
        if 'South' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = str(*rooms[current_room].values())
        else:
            print('Unable to move to that location, try again.')

    elif direction == 'go east':
        if 'East' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = str(*rooms[current_room].values())
        else:
            print('Unable to move to that location, try again.')

    elif direction == 'go west':
        if 'West' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = str(*rooms[current_room].values())
        else:
            print('Unable to move to that location, try again.')
    else:
        print('Invalid, please try again.')
```

Would like to resolve this error and move rooms correctly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 40, in <module>
    current_room = str(*rooms[current_room].values())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

Comment: I think this needs debugging (or a [mre], which this is not)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], which has tips like how to write a good title. For debugging help in the future, you'll need to make a [mre], meaning minimal code, any inputs, and desired output. That can help you catch basic mistakes or misunderstandings like this. Like, once you realize that `rooms[current_room]` is a dict and you want to select a particular value (not all values), the answer is trivial: just use indexing: `rooms[current_room][<direction>]`.

Comment: You should give your variables more logical names. The variable currently known as `direction` can hold the value "go north". But "go north" is not a direction, "North", "East", "South" and "West" are directions. So renaming this variable to something like `user_command` makes your code more readable, after that you can split this value if it starts with "go", into a new variable `direction`.

Comment: BTW, this code has a lot of repetition. You could shorten it by splitting off the command, "go", and the direction: `command, direction = user_command.split()`. Then you could have something like `if command == 'go': if direction in rooms[current_room]: ...` (This is called the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am new to coding and I will try to make this happen. So far I got the command, direction split. Working on using that to move rooms.